# apt search: limit to exact match

Tags: apt, package-management

I've been toying with Linux for quite some time now, but I never figured out this seemingly basal function of apt.

The thing is when searching for something related to Java or Python or something similar, apt finds hundreds of packages. But I want to limit the results to anything that has python as an exact name of the package.

So I tried stuff like: 
`apt search python | grep *python*` 
and so on, but never figured it out. I hate having to admit my defeat and result to webbased package details or using a graphical interface to find packets. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to see why certain packages are matching, run: `apt search --full PATTERN` and then use your terminal search feature to find matches for PATTERn

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`Apt` supports regular expression, so you can use:

```
apt search ^python$
```

which looks for a package started with a `p` followed by `ytho` and ended to the `n`, (in other words: looks exactly for `python`).

or even limit your search to the package names using:

```
apt search --names-only python
```