# Why can I not install auto-apt?

Tags: command-line, apt, 18.04, package-management, checkinstall

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

I was looking at the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoApt) on how to install `auto-apt`. However, when I run

```
apt-cache show auto-apt
```

I get

```
N: Unable to locate package auto-apt
E: No packages found
```

What happened to `auto-apt` ?

**Edit.**  This is not a duplicate of the post [apt search: limit to exact match](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934739/apt-search-limit-to-exact-match) . Below I am publishing some other results I got in the terminal.

```
$ apt search ^auto-apt$
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done

$ sudo apt-get install auto-apt
[sudo] password for username: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package auto-apt
```

Comment: Yes, there seems to be no `auto-apt` package in 18.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=auto-apt&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=bionic&section=all

Comment: Note that the same thing can be achieved with `apt-file`.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli , thank you. Your link did not work, but it [did help](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=auto-apt) . Please consider writing an answer, I will most probably accept it (after 24 hours).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apt search: limit to exact match](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934739/apt-search-limit-to-exact-match)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems auto-apt was last updated to version 0.3.24 in 2014, i.e., 5 years ago. Also, as of now xenial (16.04) seems to be the only supported release which still contains auto-apt in its repository information. In bionic (18.04) you can still download the deb package and install auto-apt. It's dependency is satisfiable. To install run

```
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/auto-apt/auto-apt_0.3.24_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i auto-apt_0.3.24_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

On a side note, since Ubuntu is a Debian based OS and all packages are imported from Debian itself, it seems Debian is also planning to drop auto-apt since it ain't available on Stretch or Buster.